# Error when inserting a tikz code in a large document

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to integrate this tikz code in my thesis, but when I do that I get 2 errors and lots of warning.

Errors :

```
1) Package tikz Error: + or - expected. ...ht=of $(A-4.east)!0.45!(A-5.east)$] (a1);
2) Missing $ inserted. ...ht=of $(A-4.east)!0.45!(A-5.east)$] (a1);
```

Both errors are in this line: `\coordinate[right=of $(A-4.east)!0.45!(A-5.east)$] (a1);`

I don't know what is wrong that I did, my document compiles perfectly before adding the tikz code.
Any idea how to solve this?

My Code :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 6mm and 15mm,
    start chain = A going below,
    ]
    \tikzstyle{base}=[rectangle, draw, thick,
    text width=8em, minimum height=3.5em, align=flush center,
    on chain=A, join=by LA]
        \tikzstyle{box}=[base, rounded corners]
    \tikzstyle{EL}=[% Edge Labels
    font=\footnotesize, align=left]
    \tikzstyle{LA}=[% Line with Arrowhead
    thick, -Stealth]


    \node [box]     {User Requirements};            % A-1
    \node [base]    {Informal Specification};
    \node [base]    {Formal Specification};
    \node [base]    {Protocol Verfication};         % A-4
    \node [base]    {Implementation Development};
    \node [base]    {Conformance Testing};
    \node [base]    {Interoperability Testing};
    \node [box]     {Maintenance};                  % A-8
    %
    \draw [LA]  (A-4.east) -- ++ (1.5,0) |-
    ($(A-2)!0.45!(A-3)$) node[EL,pos=0.25,right]{Errors\\ Detected};
    % auxilary coordinates
    \coordinate[right=of $(A-4.east)!0.45!(A-5.east)$] (a1);
    \coordinate[right=of a1] (a2);
    \draw [LA]  (A-6) -| (a1) node[EL,pos=0.75,right] {Errors\\ Detected};
    \draw [LA]  (A-7) -| (a2) node[EL,pos=0.75,right] {Errors\\ Detected};
    \draw [LA]  (a2)  -- (a2 -| A-5);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have the same libraries in your main document as are used in `standalone` document? for test, what is going on, please provide shortened main document with only this code.

Comment: yes, I have the same, along with other packages needed.

Comment: It's hard to debug when the code you show us *does* work ... You can try using `\coordinate (a1) at ($(A-4.east)!0.45!(A-5.east) + (15mm,0)$);` instead, but if you want to learn what the problem is, then you'll probably need to make a minimal example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Actually, I had a thought: try adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. oh my god it works with \usetikzlibrary{babel},  I really appreciate, thank you so much!

Comment: If you use TikZ along with the `babel` package, it's often a good idea to include that library. It depends on language though, but for some languages the character codes of certain characters are changed by the `babel` package, which messes things up when those characters are used for specific things in TikZ. The `babel` library tries to fix such incompatibilities.